# Is there a way override node_module imports to an alternate module (i.e. lodash to lodash-es)?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, node-modules, es6-modules

Testing out updating from angular 9 to angular 10 for my mono-repo.  Getting lots of the following warnings:

```
WARNING in \libs\global-search\src\lib\components\status\status.component.ts
depends on 'lodash/cloneDeep'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

To help handle the issue and reduce build sizes, I am switching over to using lodash-es.

To make things easier for my team, I would rather not to replace each import 'lodash/METHOD' with import 'lodash-es/METHOD'

so `import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual'` would point to `node_modules/lodash-es/isEqual`

Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            lodash: 'lodash-es',
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        }
    },
    ...
},
```

**Note**: I left a vue example so you can see that you can set a specific file if you need.